# Maximum spring strength coefficient relative to torque in this product

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

I work in R&D and have gotten tangled in the equations for specifying the spring for a product.

The product has a stepper motor.
An arm pivoting from the stepper motor axle is constrained 74.58mm along its length by an extension spring. (that's 74.58mm from pivot to constraint point)
The other end of the spring is on a fixed point on the motor mount that is 41.6mm from the axle/pivot. At rest, the spring is 43mm long - spring length obviously varies as the arm rotates.
The arm needs to rotate by 90 degrees away from the fixed point.
(Think of the arm and the spring as creating two sides of a triangle).

I need an equation relating the available torque of the motor, in $Nm$, to the spring coefficient in $N/m$ - so I can specify a spring given options of different motors.

The easy bit of this question is finding that the relationship between the length of the spring and the rotation of the arm is sinusoidal not linear.
The more difficult bit (I found) is with the fact that the torque exerted by the spring is also not proportional to either the spring extension or the rotation but some combination - because the spring doesn't stay perpendicular to the arm, the force gets divided.
I'm afraid I didn't complete that second part, and I know the next steps would be to combine the first two steps to find torque in terms of angle and spring coefficient, then differentiate the equation to find the maximum (because spring coefficient is constant).

Suffice to say there's plenty of trig involved, and I got stuck before I got to the calculus.

Any move forward on this would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: I think a diagram would help in understanding what you're asking.